# How to netcat to multiple ports

Tags: pipe, netcat, tee

I'am using a raspberry and i need 2 local streams. This is what i've tried:

**Attempt**

`raspivid <some options> -o - | tee nc localhost 5100 | nc localhost 5000`

**Question**

I can receive the output on `5000` but not on `5100`, what am i missing?

`raspivid -o -` spits the stream to stdout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, 'tee' does not take command names – it takes *file* names. You're writing copies of the output to files named `nc`, `localhost`, and `5100` in the current directory.

If you want to run two commands, check if your shell allows "process substitution" using `>( ... )`, automatically passing a pipe as the file name:

```
raspivid <etc> | tee >(nc localhost 5100) | nc localhost 5000
```

Alternatively, install `pee` from *moreutils*:

```
raspivid <etc> | pee "nc localhost 5100" | nc localhost 5000
```

If neither of those options are available, use `mkfifo` to create a *named* pipe for one of the 'nc' instances, then run the output and the input separately:

```
mkfifo /tmp/ncpipe
nc localhost 5100 < /tmp/ncpipe &
raspivid <etc> | tee /tmp/ncpipe | nc localhost 5000
```